# Score updating automatically without any prior collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie to C# and am currently trying to create a scoring system for Ruby's Tutorial. So I am trying to have the score update each time Ruby fixes a robot but currently the score is updating every few seconds without Ruby throwing her projectile. I have been working on this for days with no result and this is the closest I have come to having this scoring function work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Also, I am calling the score between these two scripts as instructed for completing this score function.

Ruby's Controller Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public bool vertical;
    public float changeTime = 3.0f;

    private RubyController rubyController;

    public ParticleSystem smokeEffect;
    
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    float timer;
    int direction = 1;
    bool broken = true;
    
    Animator animator;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()

    {
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        timer = changeTime;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        GameObject rubyControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("RubyController");
        
        if (rubyControllerObject != null)
        {
            rubyController = rubyControllerObject.GetComponent<RubyController>(); 
            print ("Found the RubyConroller Script!");
        }

        if (rubyController == null)
        {
            print ("Cannot find GameController Script!");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //remember ! inverse the test, so if broken is true !broken will be false and return won’t be executed.
        if(!broken)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer < 0)
        {
            direction = -direction;
            timer = changeTime;
        }
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //remember ! inverse the test, so if broken is true !broken will be false and return won’t be executed.
        if(!broken)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        Vector2 position = rigidbody2D.position;
        
        if (vertical)
        {
            position.y = position.y + Time.deltaTime * speed * direction;
            animator.SetFloat("Move X", 0);
            animator.SetFloat("Move Y", direction);
        }
        else
        {
            position.x = position.x + Time.deltaTime * speed * direction;
            animator.SetFloat("Move X", direction);
            animator.SetFloat("Move Y", 0);
        }
        
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(position);
    }
    
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        RubyController player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<RubyController>();

        if (player != null)
        {
            player.ChangeHealth(-1);
        }
        
        GameObject rubyControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("RubyController");
        if (rubyController != null)
        {
            {
                rubyController.ChangeScore(+1); 
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Public because we want to call it from elsewhere like the projectile script
    public void Fix()
    {
        broken = false;
        rigidbody2D.simulated = false;
        //optional if you added the fixed animation
        animator.SetTrigger("Fixed");
        
        smokeEffect.Stop();
    }
}
```

Enemy Controller Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;



public class RubyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.0f;
   
    public int maxHealth = 5;
    
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;

    public int Score;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    
    public AudioClip throwSound;
    public AudioClip hitSound;
    
    public int health { get { return currentHealth; }}
    int currentHealth;

    public float timeInvincible = 2.0f;
    bool isInvincible;
    float invincibleTimer;
    
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
    float horizontal;
    float vertical;
    
    public ParticleSystem HealthIncrease;
    public ParticleSystem HealthDecrease;

    Animator animator;
    Vector2 lookDirection = new Vector2(1,0);
    
    AudioSource audioSource;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        Score = 0;

        HealthIncrease.Stop();
        HealthDecrease.Stop();

    }

    public void ChangeScore(int scoreAmount)
    {
        {   
            Score++;
            scoreText.text = "Fixed Robots: " + Score.ToString();
        }
        
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
        
        if(!Mathf.Approximately(move.x, 0.0f) || !Mathf.Approximately(move.y, 0.0f))
        {
            lookDirection.Set(move.x, move.y);
            lookDirection.Normalize();
        }
        
        animator.SetFloat("Look X", lookDirection.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Look Y", lookDirection.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", move.magnitude);
        
        if (isInvincible)
        {
            invincibleTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (invincibleTimer < 0)
                isInvincible = false;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            Launch();
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rigidbody2d.position + Vector2.up * 0.2f, lookDirection, 1.5f, LayerMask.GetMask("NPC"));
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                NonPlayerCharacter character = hit.collider.GetComponent<NonPlayerCharacter>();
                if (character != null)
                {
                    character.DisplayDialog();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;
        position.x = position.x + speed * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
        position.y = position.y + speed * vertical * Time.deltaTime;

        rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
    }


    public void ChangeHealth(int amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            if (isInvincible)
                return;
            
            isInvincible = true;
            invincibleTimer = timeInvincible;
            GameObject projectileObject = Instantiate(HealthDecrease.gameObject, rigidbody2d.position + Vector2.up * 0.5f, Quaternion.identity);

            Projectile projectile = projectileObject.GetComponent<Projectile>();
            PlaySound(hitSound);
        }

        if (amount < 5)
        {
            GameObject projectileObject = Instantiate(HealthIncrease.gameObject, rigidbody2d.position + Vector2.up * 0.5f, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        

        currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth + amount, 0, maxHealth);
        
        UIHealthBar.instance.SetValue(currentHealth / (float)maxHealth);
    }
    
    void Launch()
    {
        GameObject projectileObject = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, rigidbody2d.position + Vector2.up * 0.5f, Quaternion.identity);

        Projectile projectile = projectileObject.GetComponent<Projectile>();
        projectile.Launch(lookDirection, 300);

        animator.SetTrigger("Launch");
        
        PlaySound(throwSound);

    } 

    public void PlaySound(AudioClip clip)
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the score to update when something is fixed, would it make sense to put `ChangeScore` inside Fix() maybe?

Comment: Thank you so much that was exactly the issue!!

Comment: Great. I guess I’ll post it as an answer.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the section:

```
GameObject rubyControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("RubyController");
if (rubyController != null)
{
    {
        rubyController.ChangeScore(+1); 
    }
}
```

Into `public void Fix()` will ensure it’s only executed when a robot is fixed.